# Heatmap Data Label color to red based on X and Y coordinates

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying to highlight a single cell datalabel based on x and y coordinates of heatmap. [refer this fiddle, where it is implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/303/) as i'm using it inside jasper this approach is not working properly. Can any one show me how to do it using formatter.

```
series:{ 
     data: data,
     dataLabels: {
                /*formatter:function(){ i'm having x and y cordinates and i wanted to plot the lable color and it should be surrounded with a square as given in sample fiddle*/}}
```

TIA

Comment: Do you need to use formatter? I think it's easier since you know x&y to set options directly for that specific point's label: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/304/

Comment: @PawełFus ur sol. is right when x and y are static i.e we already know those values, in my case these are coming from a URL so i've to fetch them into variable and then use them. I've tried using the above fiddle method but i'm getting export issues in jasper. i'm trying to use this way inside series.dataLabels.formatter:function() { if(this.point.x = url_x && this.point.y = url_y) color:'red' else color:'black' }. Is there any possibility?

Comment: There's no such way. You can return formatted `<span>` tag with styles, but not all of them will be translated into the SVG/VML. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/305/ If you don't want to use `exporting` from Highcharts (or exported image can be a bit different), then set `useHTML` flag to true: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/306/

Comment: ok. I'll try this way @PawełFus. Thanks a lot for your support.